# Check if subset contains said value

Tags: r, function, loops

I have been struggling with a problem of creating a matrix which would give information about if value is in the subset of another dataset.

To show an example:

we have df, which contains several information: sub_ID, condition and a number.

```
sub_ID <- c("sub01", "sub02", "sub03")
condition <- c("A", "B", "C")
number <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) 
df< - data.frame(sub_ID, condition, number)
```

Then we have a test_df, which has corresponding sub_ID and condition but only some of the numbers.

I want R to create a new variable in df, which will give me 1, when for sub_ID and condition stored in the same row as number, in the test df there is this number.

To give an example - let's say that for sub01, for condition A, we have numbers 5, 8, 24. This information is represented in test_df, in three columns.
In df I have sub01, condition A and a range of number form 1 to 25, in 25 rows. I want to check for each of these rows if for sub01, condition A appeared this number. So, I want R to give me **0** in row 1,2,3 and 4 then **1** in row 5, then  **0** in rows 6 and 7, then **1** in row 8 and so on.

What would be a solution here? I tried to write a custom function, with the loop, but I cannot make it work.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please show your `test_df`

Comment: Do you mean test_df? It looks like this:
sub_ID <- c("sub01", sub02",...)
condition <- c("A", "B",...)
number <- c(5,8,24...)
Numbers are different for each subject, each condition in the test_df

Comment: You have a reproducible example in 'df'.  If you can show the same with test_df and your expected output, it would be great

Comment: Perhaps this helps `library(data.table); setDT(df)[test_df, new := number %in% i.number, on = .(sub_ID, condition)]`

Comment: @akrun It seems very neat! Thank you - one question though. I get an error with the i.number. Can you explain to me what is it referring to? What is i. here?

Comment: I assumed that you have a column `number` in `test_df`, then, `i.number` refers to that column name as `number` is also a column name in 'df'

Comment: I keep getting this mistake: 
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df), test_df, `:=`(new, number %in% : 
logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided.

Would it be possible for you to help me with that one?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example for testing

Comment: ###df

sub_ID <- c("sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01")
condition <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
number <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(sub_ID, condition, number)


###test_df
test_sub_ID <- c("sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01")
test_condition <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")
test_number <- c(2,7,1,4,8,9)
test_df <- data.frame(sub_ID, condition, number)


library(data.table); setDT(df)[test_df, new := number %in% i.test_number, on = .(test_sub_ID, test_condition)]

Comment: Your `test_df` should be `test_df <- data.frame(test_sub_ID, test_condition, test_number)`

Comment: If that is the case, `setDT(df)[test_df, new := number %in% test_number, on = .(sub_ID = test_sub_ID, condition = test_condition)]` works

Comment: Now it works! But I am not sure if it does, what I need. You see, now in the new column I can see TRUE in first row, even though for sub01, condition A there was no 1 in the test_df. Is it possible for the function to take two conditions simultaneously?

Comment: @akrun - do you have an idea, how to have two conditions at the same time?