# How to check if a data frame contains a value defined in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, conditional-statements

I am trying to solve a problem: to create a new variable with values 0 or 1 to define if a data frame contains a value stored in one column. I asked this question previously ([Check if subset contains said value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73503831/check-if-subset-contains-said-value)) and I got a tip to use setDT() function.
It works, but I have trouble using it for two conditions. To explain briefly:

1. I have two data frames:

```
###df 
sub_ID <- c("sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01") 
condition <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B") 
number <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3) 
df <- data.frame(sub_ID, condition, number) 

###test_df 
test_sub_ID <- c("sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01", "sub01") 
test_condition <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C") 
test_number <- c(2,7,1,4,8,9) 
test_df <- data.frame(test_sub_ID, test_condition, test_number)
```

2. I want to check row-wise, if each number from df is present in test_df, according to two features.
   So - if in df I have the first row, the number is 1, I want to check if in test_df there was 1 for sub01, in condition A, together.
3. I got the answer that I should use this function:
   setDT(df)[test_df, new := number %in% test_number, on = .(sub_ID = test_sub_ID, condition = test_condition)]

Thank you, @akrun!

4. The problem is I want to have two conditions included at the same time, meanwhile, it seems not to work as I want it to.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: In the solution, `setDT` just makes a `"data.table"` out of a data frame, more important is the code in the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the rows of `df` using subset in `apply` and count the `nrow`.

```
df$test <- apply(df, 1, \(x) nrow(subset(test_df, test_sub_ID == x[1] & 
                                           test_condition == x[2] & 
                                           test_number == x[3])))

df
#   sub_ID condition number test
# 1  sub01         A      1    0
# 2  sub01         A      2    1
# 3  sub01         A      3    0
# 4  sub01         B      1    1
# 5  sub01         B      2    0
# 6  sub01         B      3    0
```

This is similar to this `for` loop which should help you to understand the code and how to write such code by yourself. Use the `apply` above though because it is much faster!

```
df$test <- NA
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  df$test[i] <- nrow(subset(test_df, test_sub_ID == df[i, 1] & 
                              test_condition == df[i, 2] & 
                              test_number == df[i, 3]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your `data.table` join approach:

```
setnames(setDT(test_df), new=names(df))
test_df[setDT(df), j=.N, by=.EACHI, on=.(sub_ID, condition, number)]
```

Output:

```
   sub_ID condition number test
1:  sub01         A      1    0
2:  sub01         A      2    1
3:  sub01         A      3    0
4:  sub01         B      1    1
5:  sub01         B      2    0
6:  sub01         B      3    0
```

Note: I use `setnames()` as a convenience only: Making the names of `test_df` the same as the names of `df` facilitates a more concise `on=` clause.